# How do I use elements inside <xsl:value-of>

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I wanted to build a file in XML that could hold both text and code, like this:

```
<root>
    <item>Use the <code>location.href</code> propriety to change the URL.</item>
<item>Something else.</item>
</root>
```

And I wanted to create a XSLT file to convert that XML into this HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Use the <code>location.href</code> propriety to change the URL.</li>
            <li>Something else.</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried to use this XSLT code, but it outputed the HTML ignoring the `<code>` tag. The content of it still was visible, but the tag itself (and its formatation) was nowhere to be found.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="root/item">
                <li><xsl:value-of select="." /></li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I also tried to replace in the XML file `<code>` with `&lt;code&gt;`, but the result was the same.

Please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a template matching the `<item>`s and then use [`xsl:copy-of`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256183(v=vs.110).aspx) - with which copies all sub-content - instead of `xsl:value-of` - which only copies the text content.
`node()` selects all nodes(emphasis on elements and text nodes).

```
<xsl:template match="/root">
    <html>
        <body>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates />
            </ul>
        </body> 
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="item">
    <li><xsl:copy-of select="node()" /></li>
</xsl:template>
```

Output is as desired.